# XSLT Align different children plain text file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am still learning my XSLT, I have a XML doc that has 2 different children and I need to line up my employee data, Selection1, and Selection2. So the employee data works as expected and so does the data for employees that have both Selection1 and Selection2 but when an employee has one or the other I cannot get the proper spacing, i.e. Selection2 data starts where Selection1 data starts if there is no Selection1 data.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Example XML:

```
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>QWERDFHUJKSDK123</Employee_ID>
    <Employee_Last_Name>Smith</Employee_Last_Name>
    <Employee_First_Name>Trent</Employee_First_Name>
    <Selection1>
        <Selection1Type>1234</Selection1Type>
        <Selection1Date>2017-01-01</Selection1Date>
        <Selection1Data>963258741</Selection1Data>
    </Selection1>
    <Selection2>
        <Selection2Type>9638</Selection2Type>
        <Selection2Date>2017-01-01</Selection2Date>
        <Selection2Data>963258741</Selection2Data>
    </Selection2>
   </employee>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>XCOIUEWRJFKLD</Employee_ID>
    <Employee_Last_Name>Bishop</Employee_Last_Name>
    <Employee_First_Name>Walter</Employee_First_Name>
    <Selection1>
        <Selection1Type>1234</Selection1Type>
        <Selection1Date>2017-01-01</Selection1Date>
        <Selection1Data>963258741</Selection1Data>
    </Selection1>
</employee>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>SDALFKJDSLLSDF</Employee_ID>
    <Employee_Last_Name>Farnsworth</Employee_Last_Name>
    <Employee_First_Name>Astrid</Employee_First_Name>
    <Selection2>
        <Selection2Type>9638</Selection2Type>
        <Selection2Date>2017-01-01</Selection2Date>
        <Selection2Data>963258741</Selection2Data>
    </Selection2>
</employee>
```

Example XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet"        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


  <!-- Variables -->
 <xsl:variable name="Pad50" select="'                                                  '"/>
  <xsl:variable name="NewLine">
    <xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>


  <xsl:output indent="no" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">


    <!-- ************************************************* -->
    <!-- Employee                                          -->
    <!-- ************************************************* -->

    <xsl:for-each select="Employee">


      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Employee_ID, $Pad50), 1, 20)"/>


      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Employee_Last_Name, $Pad50), 1, 20)"/>


      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Employee_First_Name, $Pad50), 1, 27)"/>



      <!-- ************************************************* -->
      <!-- Filler Rows                                       -->
      <!-- ************************************************* -->


      <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 7)"/> 


      <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 19)"/> 


      <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 106)"/>



      <!-- ************************************************* -->
      <!-- Selection1                                        -->
      <!-- ************************************************* -->

    <xsl:for-each select="Selection1">


      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Selection1Type ='1234'">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Selection1Type, $Pad50), 1, 4)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 4)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>


      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Selection1Type = '1234'">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(format-date(Selection1Date, '[M01][D01][Y0001]'), $Pad50), 1, 8)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 8)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>


      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Selection1Type = '1234'">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Selection1Data, $Pad50), 1, 10)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 10)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>


      <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 19)"/>

    </xsl:for-each>

      <!-- ************************************************* -->
      <!-- Selection2                                        -->
      <!-- ************************************************* -->

      <xsl:for-each select="Selection2">


        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="Selection2Type ='9638'">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Selection2Type, $Pad50), 1, 4)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 4)"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="Selection2Type = '9638'">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(format-date(Selection2Date, '[M01][D01][Y0001]'), $Pad50), 1, 8)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 8)"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="Selection2Type = '9638'">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Selection2Data, $Pad50), 1, 10)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 10)"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


        <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 19)"/>

      </xsl:for-each>


      <xsl:value-of select="$NewLine"/>    
    </xsl:for-each>




  </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that your XML is not well-formed. You have an opening `<Employee>` tag, but a closing `</employee>` tag. Additionally, you do not have a single root element.

Assuming these are just issues with your question, the reason you are having trouble is with your use of `xsl:for-each`. In the case of there being no `Selection` element, nothing gets output, and so your `Selection2` with start in the wrong position.

The simplest fix is to add a check for any `Selection1` element after the `xsl:for-each` to add some padding of the right length

```
<xsl:if test="not(Selection1)">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 41)"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Alternatively, if there can never be more than one `Selection1` or `Selection2` then you don't really need `xsl:for-each` at all.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:variable name="Pad50" select="'                                                  '"/>
  <xsl:variable name="NewLine">
    <xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:output indent="no" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="Employee">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Employee_ID, $Pad50), 1, 20)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Employee_Last_Name, $Pad50), 1, 20)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Employee_First_Name, $Pad50), 1, 27)"/>

      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Selection1/Selection1Type, $Pad50), 1, 4)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Selection1/Selection1Type = '1234'">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(format-date(Selection1/Selection1Date, '[M01][D01][Y0001]'), $Pad50), 1, 8)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 8)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Selection1/Selection1Data, $Pad50), 1, 10)"/>

       <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 1)"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Selection2/Selection2Type, $Pad50), 1, 4)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="Selection2/Selection2Type = '9638'">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(format-date(Selection2/Selection2Date, '[M01][D01][Y0001]'), $Pad50), 1, 8)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($Pad50, 1, 8)"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Selection2/Selection2Data, $Pad50), 1, 10)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$NewLine"/>    
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim, you rock sir! I was so over thinking the issue. My apologies for the XML I could not post the true XML I am using due to the data in it so that was a hand made example of what a portion of the file looked like.